# Elasticsearch does not start on Ubuntu 14.04, possible error with lucene dependency

Tags: ubuntu, java, elasticsearch, lucene

I have tried installing the elasticsearch package using apt on Ubuntu 14.04, but when I run `sudo service elasticsearch status`, I get the following output:

```
 * elasticsearch is not running
```

I tried running `sudo service elasticsearch start`, and it claims to start OK.

However, no logs are recorded in /var/log/elasticsearch.

I tried running `sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`, and got the following output:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_7_0_0
        at org.elasticsearch.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:50)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:76)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:287)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:159)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:150)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:115)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
```

What could be causing this error?

The elasticsearch documentation does not seem to include information on how to install lucene or where to configure its installation.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 is past end of life. Upgrade to a supported Ubuntu release.

Comment: Please check class path and make sure it have all dependent jars.

Comment: I have upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 and am still getting the error.

Comment: How do I check the class path? How do I make sure it has all dependent jars?